# Derivative of a taylor polynomial with respect to the center

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider a taylor polynomial of degree $n$ and centered at $a$ :$$T_n(x,a) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$

Differentiating $T_n$ with respect to $a$ gives a nice result :
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(x,a) = \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

I've been trying to understand this result. It seems to suggest that if we change the center $a$ by a small bit, the change in the value of taylor polynomial depends only on the $(x-a)^n$ term. All other preceding terms vanished. I couldn't wrap my head around why $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$ doesn't depend on the lesser order terms. I'm pretty sure there exists some intuitive explanation for this. Any help?

(I got above result using `telescoping`. Kindly let me know if you want to see the work...)

Comment: A possible interpretation is: $T_n(\cdot, a)$ is independent of $a$ if and only if $f^{n+1} \equiv 0$, i.e. iff $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's state that the Taylor series has only terms up to $f^{(n)}(a)$, i.e. all further derivatives $f^{(m)}(a) =  0$ for $m >n$. Then careful telescoping gives

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(x,a) \\
= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{(k-1)!}(x-a)^{k-1} \\
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k \\
= 0
$$

If infinitely many nonzero derivatives exist, then telescoping also gives $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(x,a)  = 0$ as the trick with the "last term" doesn't exist.

In summary, $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(x,a)  = 0$ which is interpreted: it doesn't matter where you expand, the function is always the same. As it should be, since Taylor series can be performed about any point as long as the function is continuous and $n$-times (where all further derivatives are zero, or $n$ be $\infty$) differentiable in the considered range.

Comment: Ahh `it doesn't matter where you expand, the function is always the same` you've put it so elegantly! I get it now. Thank you so much! You made my day XD

Comment: For $f(x) = x^2$ we have $T_1(x, a) = a^2+2a(x-a)$, which is not independent of $a$. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Your claim $f^{(m)}(a) =  0$ for $m > n$ looks suspicious to me. That does not hold in general.

Comment: @MartinR You're right, this doesn't hold in general. I discuss two cases (please see main text): 1.  where the Taylor series has only terms up to $f^{(n)}(a)$, i.e. all further derivatives are then $f^{(m)}(a) =  0$ for $m >n$.  This is what the OP is adressing, if I understood it correctly. 2.  infinitely many nonzero derivatives exist. The conclusion is that in both cases $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(x,a)  = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question and/or the answer. But $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(x,a)  = 0$ does not hold in general, it holds only if $f^{n+1} \equiv 0$, i.e. if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$ (and then $T_n(x, a) = f(x)$ for all $a$).

Comment: @MartinR I guess I see now what you mean: what one cannot do is to cut off a function's Taylor series after the nth term, if the Taylor series indeed has more than $n$ terms. In that case, $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(x,a) \ne 0 $. I didn't understand the question in that way, however. The way I understood it is that the Taylor series indeed has only  n terms. If $n$ is finite, then the function is a polynomial, if $n$ is infinite, then all functions are fine which can be Taylor-expanded.

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't wrap my head around why $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$ doesn't depend on the lesser order terms.

For any polynomial $p$ of degree $\le n$ we have
$$
 T_n(f+p; x, a) = T_n(f; x, a) + T_n(p; x, a) = T_n(f; x, a) + p(x)
$$
because the Taylor polynomial of $p$ is $p$ itself. It follows that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(f+p; x,a) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(f; x,a)
$$
which means that $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} T_n(f; x,a)$ does not change if $f$ is modified in way that changes only $f, f', \ldots f^{(n)}$.

Another interpretation is that $T(\cdot, a)$ is independent of $a$ if and only if $f^{(n+1)} \equiv 0$, i.e. if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$.

Comment: Brilliance! $p(x)$ of degree $n$ doesn't contribute to the changes because its taylor polynomial is itself! This means for any choice of $a$,  the corresponding coefficients of the lower order terms in the taylor series don't change. You're obviously a math god <3 Seriously what should I do to see these clearly like you?